# Apache error: AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching Directory

Tags: apache, centos7

I'm using Centos7, Apache, and Laravel 5.8.
I have made a vHost using apache, and place the Laravel direcoty:
The directory was exist and permitable.
This is the vHost configuration.

```
<VirtualHost segara.id:80>
    ServerName segara.id
    ServerAlias segara.id
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/live/segara/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/live/segara/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "| /usr/sbin/rotatelogs -l -n 5 /var/www/html/live/segara/storage/logs/http/http-errors.log 86400"
    CustomLog "| /usr/sbin/rotatelogs -l -n 5 /var/www/html/live/segara/storage/logs/http/http-requests.log 86400" combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The problem was:
When I accessed segara.id, the web display as Apache Tesing 123

[image]

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using https?

Answer (score 0):

If in your server only serving one web,
I think you can try to change your config on:

```
<VirtualHost segara.id:80>
```

to be:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Then try again

CMIIW

Thank you